# CryptoLicensing error

Tags: .net, cryptolicensing

I'm currently evaluating several licensing apps for .NET and the one I found easier to work and feature-wise is CryptoLicensing.

I downloaded CryptoLicensing v2011, configured the License Activation WebService, ran the install.aspx steps and I got an sql server database with 5 tables.

Then I went to the app and tried to generate a license and I got an error message saying "Cannot insert value NULL into column 'ID'". I checked with SQL Profiler and in fact this column (which is the primary key column) doesn't appear in the insert statement.
I noticed that the License table had 5 columns: ID, LicenseCode, MachineCode, LicSetting_ID, LicSetting_LicenseCode. So I changed the table definition: set the ID as nullable and removed it from the PK and set the LicSetting_ID as PK.

Then I was able to generate licenses and validate. Now I'd like to know if everyone is having this issue or if I did something wrong..

I was thinking in buying CryptoLicensing but I don't want to have to "hack" the database to make it work.

Best regards,
Manuel Felício.

Comment: Perhaps it was an identity column?

Comment: Nope..the ID column is a varchar(20)

Comment: If you're really thinking of buying it then you should email the problem to their sales guys and get them to drive through a fix to get your sale.

Comment: I know, but I just couldn't do the most basic thing which is to generate a license.. maybe someone else already had this problem because I just tried followed the instructions and hit GENERATE.. I didn't do anything wierd

Comment: But you could when you'd hacked it. I really think you ought to take this to them, then they'll give you a new demo that does work out-of-the-box and you can re-evaluate it. Sorry I haven't used this myself.

Comment: The user has contacted us and we have replied explaining the cause and resolution.

Comment: Should have contacted the company before bad mouthing them.

Comment: @Lucifer: You install a trial software using the "next-next-next" approach and because you didn't fill an optional field the application throws an SQL error. I think it's valid to expose the problem here, because I'm sure someone else will find the same issue. Usually contacting a company's support could take days to get an answer and stack overflow takes hours or even minutes and I'm sure you, me and most people here have short deadlines to meet and waiting days for an answer isn't an option when you could wait minutes.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted their support and they replied me quickly and effectively (less than 10 minutes) enough to make me state this here.

The problem was that I didn't specify a table prefix when I created the licensing tables from within the management application. The license service creates a table named License and the application creates a table named prefix+'License', which caused the errors.

Anyway, it wasn't clear to me that it was mandaroty to specify a table prefix. Apart from that, it is working now.